# Why can I not access an instance of class that is created in a constructor ( Java )

Tags: java, constructor, scope, instance

To preface the question, I'm very new to Java.

I have classes called, Game, Player, and SystemIO.
My main() is in the Game class. Below is it's code

```
public static void main(String[] args){
SystemIO systemIO = new SystemIO();
}
```

Once SystemIO is called, it's constructor creates an instance of Player with the line

```
 Player player = new Player("Bob");
```

where the Player constructor takes 1 argument as a String.

Further down in the SystemIO class I have a method that accesses information from "player" the instance.

```
player.getName();
```

When I try to do this, the console reports 
**SystemIO.java:339: error: cannot find symbol**

I have checked that I am not trying to reference the class name with a capital "Player."
Like I said, I'm extremely new to Java and just trying to wrap my head around it and I believe it's a scope issue...but I'm not sure.

Edit to add reproducible code:

Game.java

```
package com.myapps;
import com.myapps.system.SystemIO;

public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SystemIO systemIO = new SystemIO();
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
package com.myapps.player;

public class Player{
    String name;
    public Player(String playerName){
        name = playerName;
    }
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}
```

SystemIO.java

```
package com.myapps.system;
import com.myapps.player.Player;

public class SystemIO{
    public SystemIO(){
        Player player = new Player("Bob");
        readPlayerName();
    }

    public void readPlayerName(){
        System.out.println(player.getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly because of scope. Unfortunately, you have not included enough code to say for sure. Edit your question into a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Describing the code is not helpful.

Comment: It was definitely a scope error. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `public readPlayerName(){` should be a compiler error. You're missing the return type. Which I assume should have been `public void readPlayerName(){` - **and** you can also pass variables to your methods. So that ***could*** have been `public void readPlayerName(Player player)` and then you could pass the `player` to the method (in addition to making it a class field as in the provided answer).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch right you are. I fixed it. In the actual code the return type is there and valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make player a class variable.

Put someone in your class:

```
Player player;
```

and change the code of your constructor to:

```
player = new Player("Bob");
```

This is called a scope error. A variable that you want to be accessable to ALL the methods of the class, should be declared IN the class and not in ONE specific method (in your case, you did it in the constructor)

Comment: Of course. I couldn't see the forest for the trees. That makes sense. I'll modify and see if that does it. Thank you.